# Initialize an int[] in a method call as a parameter

Tags: arrays, c, function

I have a method like this:

```
int find_min(int[]){

   //Do Something
}
```

I have to call like this:

```
int distance = find_min({1,2,3});
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a method like this:

C doesn't have [methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)), just functions.

To pass an integer array to a function, you can pass it as a pointer or an array. Either way, you have to give it a name.

- As a pointer `int find_min(int *foo)`
- As an array `int find_min(int foo[])`

The problem, with both, is you don't know how large the array is. You'll have to pass in the size of the array as well.

```
int find_min(int foo[], size_t size) {
    int min = INT_MAX;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        if( foo[i] < min ) {
            min = foo[i];
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

---

To call it, you're almost there. The array syntax `{...}` is for [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)#C_family_of_languages). You need to first assign it to a variable.

```
    int a[] = {3, 1, 2};
    int min = find_min(a, 3);
    printf("%d\n", min);
```

You could also use a "compound literal" introduced in C99, but best to leave this as a curiosity for now.

```
    int min = find_min((int []){3, 1, 2}, 3);
```

Comment: _To call it, you're almost there. The array syntax `{...}` is only available for initialization._ Couldn't you use a compound literal if the function takes an `int *` as an argument though? Then you could call the function like so: `find_min((int [3]) {3, 1, 2}, 3);`

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 That is not syntax I've ever seen before.

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe it's not very common, but I find compound literals to be useful in some cases.

Comment: is it okay if I pass a length of an array in the function rather than as a parameter? Also, I'm new to c, so I only know the sizeof function to find the size of an array. could I use that?

Comment: @SmitPatel No, `sizeof(array)` will only give you the number of elements if the compiler already knows it, as with `int array[3]` or `int array[] = {1,2,3}`. `int array[]` and `int *array` just point to the start of memory. You can make a struct that has the pointer and size. You can end when you hit a special number, that's how strings work. You can use `int *array[]`, an array of int *pointers*, and end when you hit NULL. You can use [a library that takes care of this for you](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.66/glib-Arrays.html), but it's good to understand how memory works.